# Correlation between residuals of two different relations

Tags: regression, correlation, residuals, multivariate-regression

I have two relations,  A=f(B) and C=f(B). They both are different physical quantities depending on the same variable (let's say pressure=A  density=B, temperature=C).  I fit both relations to my data. Then I plot the residuals of A=f(B) against the ones of C=g(B). What does a correlation between them mean?
Thanks everyone!

Comment: Do you really intend that (B,A) and (B,C) have *identical* relations "f"?

Comment: No, sorry. I mean A=f(B) and C=g(B)

Comment: Hard to know without more information. It could mean that there is some additional parameter dependence that would require an SEM to analyze.